# Is there a way to work with named pipes in PyFileSystem?

Tags: pyfilesystem

Is there a way to create and work with named pipes in PyFileSystem? I don't see a reference to `fifo` or `pipe` in the [docs](https://pyfilesystem.readthedocs.io).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently. While it would be possible to implement a `FS.pipe` method, it could only work with a Linux filesystem. It wouldn't be clear what it should do on the other supported filesystems.

If you want to create a named pipe within an OSFS, you could get the *syspath* with `FS.getsyspath` and create the pipe with `os.mkfifo`.